# How to create custom d file that works with specific file mapping

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have declared a module for an internal javascript library so I can use said library in my typescript project. Let's say this library has 3 React components.

```js
declare module 'internal-js-library' {
  import { FC } from 'react';

  type ComponentAProps = { ... };
  type ComponentBProps = { ... };
  type ComponentCProps = { ... };

  export const ComponentA: FC<ComponentAProps>;
  export const ComponentB: FC<ComponentCProps>;
  export const ComponentC: FC<ComponentBProps>;
}
```

This works as expected. Now I have full types when I use this library on a typescript file

```js
import { ComponentA, ComponentC } from 'internal-js-library' ;
```

But when importing directly like this, `ComponentA`, `ComponentB` and `ComponentC` will be bundled when generating a build, even if I am not using `ComponentB`. I want to avoid that.

The solution would be to import `ComponentA` and `ComponentC` directly. However, `ComponentA` and `ComponentC` are no longer typed. Typescript no longer recognizes their type.

```js
import ComponentA from 'internal-js-library/lib/ComponentA/ComponentA';
import ComponentC from 'internal-js-library/lib/ComponentC/ComponentC';
```

A workaround for this would be:

```js
declare module 'internal-js-library/lib/ComponentA/ComponentA' {
  import { FC } from 'react';

  type ComponentAProps = { ... };

  const ComponentA: FC<ComponentAProps>;

  export default ComponentA;
}

declare module 'internal-js-library/lib/ComponentC/ComponentC' {
  import { FC } from 'react';

  type ComponentCProps = { ... };

  const ComponentC: FC<ComponentCProps>;

  export default ComponentC;
}
```

But now doing the following no longer works:

```js
import { ComponentA, ComponentC } from 'internal-js-library'
```

How can I elegantly write my definition file so both `internal-js-library/lib/ComponentX/ComponentX` and `internal-js-library` can work?

At first I thought of doing something like this, but I can't figure it out. Doesn't seems right

```js
declare module 'internal-js-library/lib/ComponentA/ComponentA' {
  import { FC } from 'react';

  type ComponentAProps = { ... };

  const ComponentA: FC<ComponentAProps>;

  export default ComponentA;
}

declare module 'internal-js-library/lib/ComponentB/ComponentB' {
  import { FC } from 'react';

  type ComponentBProps = { ... };

  const ComponentB: FC<ComponentBProps>;

  export default ComponentB;
}

declare module 'internal-js-library/lib/ComponentC/ComponentC' {
  import { FC } from 'react';

  type ComponentCProps = { ... };

  const ComponentC: FC<ComponentCProps>;

  export default ComponentC;
}

declare module 'internal-js-library' {
  import ComponentA from 'internal-js-library/lib/ComponentA/ComponentA';
  import ComponentB from 'internal-js-library/lib/ComponentA/ComponentA';
  import ComponentC from 'internal-js-library/lib/ComponentA/ComponentA';

  export ComponentA; // this gives an error

  export ComponentA: typeof ComponentA; // I'd have to rename the ComponentA on the import
}
```